# Read in Python a wav file to which data is being appended

Tags: python, wav

I need to transcribe the speech that is being written to a `wav` file. I've implemented the following iterator to try to incrementally read the audio from the file:

```
import wave
def read_audio(path, chunk_size=1024):
    wave_file = wave.open(open(path, 'rb'))
    while True:
        data = wave_file.readframes(chunk_size)
        if data != "":
            yield data
```

In order to test the generator, I've implemented a function that keeps writing to a `wav` file the audio captured by the computer's microphone:

```
import pyaudio
def record_to_file(out_path):
    fmt = pyaudio.paInt16
    channels = 1
    rate = 16000
    chunk = 1024
    audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    stream = audio.open(format=fmt, channels=channels,
                        rate=rate, input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=chunk)
    wave_file = wave.open(out_path, 'wb')
    wave_file.setnchannels(channels)
    wave_file.setsampwidth(audio.get_sample_size(fmt))
    wave_file.setframerate(rate)
    while True:
        data = stream.read(chunk)
        waveFile.writeframes(data)
```

Below is the test script:

```
import threading
import time

WAV_PATH='out.wav'

def record_worker():
    record_to_file(WAV_PATH)

if __name__=='__main__':
    t = threading.Thread(target=record_worker)
    t.setDaemon(True)
    t.start()
    time.sleep(5)
    reader = read_audio(WAV_PATH)
    for chunk in reader:
        print(len(chunk))
```

It doesn't work as I'd expect - the reader stops yielding after a while. Since the test is successful if I adapt `record_file` to set the `wav` file's `nframes` to a very large number beforehand and do the writing with `writeframesraw`, my guess is that `wave.open` eagerly reads `nframes`, not trying to read anything after that number of frames has been read.

Is it possible to obtain that incremental read in Python 2.7 without resorting to this `setnframes` hack? It's worth noting that, contrary to the test script, I have no control of the `wav` file's generation in the scenario in which I plan to utilize such feature. The writing gets done by a SWIG-adapted C library named `pjsip` (http://www.pjsip.org/python/pjsua.htm), so I don't expect it to be possible to do any modifications on that end.

Comment: Unlikely: you'd expect your reader to respect the size information set in the header. If the docs don't mention anything, I'd guess that your hack is the way to go.

Comment: I've updated my question - I don't have that control over the wav file in my production setting.

Comment: Makes sense. Ideally you can get away with the same hack on the reading side. Take a careful look at `wave_file` in the reader and see if you can keep increasing the expected number of frames as you read.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the library docs and source please?

Comment: I've added the lib and a link to its docs into the question. Please take a look.

Comment: I meant the reading library. The writing library is essentially irrelevant here. Your test script is, I'm sure, a faithful enough representation.

Comment: Nvm. I'm on mobile, so moving slow. Didn't realize wave is built into python.

Comment: Sorry, my bad - tt's stdlib's `wave`. Docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/wave.html . Source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/wave.py

Comment: Here's an idea: what happens if your call `getnframes` before each read? If it works like `setnframes`, it will look up the updated value with a seek operation. Otherwise, you might have to rewind, reread the header, and go back to the original position.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179351/discussion-between-bsam-and-mad-physicist).